# Push value into object

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
const post = [
    { postTitle: 'Title1', key: 'key1' },
    { postTitle: 'Title2', key: 'key2' }
];

const comment = [
    { key: 'key1', c: 'comment1' },
    { key: 'key1', c: 'comment2' },
    { key: 'key2', c: 'commentA' },
    { key: 'key2', c: 'commentB' },
    { key: 'key2', c: 'commentC' }
];
```

And I want to end up with the following result:

```
const newPost = [
    {
        postTitle: 'Title1',
        key: 'key1',
        comment: ['comment1', 'comment2']
    },
    {
        postTitle: 'Title2',
        key: 'key2',
        comment: ['commentA', 'commentB', 'commentC']
    }
];
```

The following code seems to almost do the job, but it is overwriting my comments. I only get the last comment of each `postTitle`.  How can I fix the code or improve the code to give me exactly like the result above?

Here is the code in question:

```
for (var i = 0; i < post.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < comment.length; j++) {
        if (post[i].key === comment[j].key) {
            post[i].comment = [];
            post[i].comment.push([comment[j].c]);
        } else {
            console.log('no comment to add');
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if there is a more elegant refactor code, please share it here.  Thank you.

Comment: Few quick heads-ups: **(1)** `comment: {"commentA", "commentB", "commentC"}` is not valid, it looks like you want an array `[...]` instead of an object `{...}`. **(2)**: `{postTitle : 'Title2', key = 'key2'}` is also invalid. You're declaring key/values with an `=` instead of `:`. **(3)** Slightly pedantic perhaps but there is no such thing as a "JSON Object". JSON is a **string** representation *of an object*. :)

Answer (score 1):

**The Issue**

The issue with your code, as you point out, is that you're overwriting the comments array. The problem lies here:

```
post[i].comment = [];
```

You should only execute the above line *if the array does not yet exist*, rather than every time.

Replacing the line above with a simple conditional check would work:

```
if (!post[i].comment) post[i].comment = [];
```

```js
const post = [{postTitle : 'Title1', key: 'key1'},{postTitle : 'Title2', key: 'key2'}];
const comment = [{key : 'key1', c: "comment1"},{key : 'key1', c: "comment2"},{key : 'key2', c: "commentA"},{key : 'key2', c: "commentB"},{key : 'key2', c: "commentC"}];

for (var i = 0; i < post.length; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < comment.length; j++) {
    if (post[i].key === comment[j].key) {
      if (!post[i].comment) post[i].comment = [];
      post[i].comment.push([comment[j].c]);
    } else {
      console.log('no comment to add');
    }
  }
}

console.log(post);
```

---

**Suggested Refactor**

I'd use `map()` for the outer iteration, and `reduce()` for the inner.

The inner [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) retrieves the related comments and returns them as an array.  The outside [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) adds these comments as a property to the `post` (and returns the modified posts as a new array).

```js
const post = [{postTitle : 'Title1', key: 'key1'},{postTitle : 'Title2', key: 'key2'}];
const comments = [{key : 'key1', c: "comment1"},{key : 'key1', c: "comment2"},{key : 'key2', c: "commentA"},{key : 'key2', c: "commentB"},{key : 'key2', c: "commentC"}];

const result = post.map(post => {

  post.comments = comments.reduce((out,comment) => {    //Optimized .filter() + .map()
    if (comment.key === post.key) out.push(comment.c); 
    return out;
  }, []);
  
  return post;

});
  
console.log(result);
```

To address earlier comments, though I believe `.filter()` + `.map()` to result in cleaner looking code, I've elected to use `.reduce()` to combine them. This is solely for sake of efficiency; I prefer one inner loop to two.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach scans the comments once to combine them and then uses the generated object as a lookup for mapping the posts:

```js
const combine = (posts, comments) => {
  const keyedComments = comments .reduce (
    (a, {key, c}) => (a [key] = (a [key] || [] ) .concat(c), a),
    {}
  )
  return posts .map ( ({key, ...rest}) => ({
    ...rest, 
    comment: keyedComments [key] || []
  }))
}

const post = [{postTitle : 'Title1', key: 'key1'}, {postTitle : 'Title2', key: 'key2'}]
const comment = [{key : 'key1', c: "comment1"}, {key : 'key1', c: "comment2"}, {key : 'key2', c: "commentA"}, {key : 'key2', c: "commentB"}, {key : 'key2', c: "commentC"}]

console .log (
  combine (post, comment)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, I have added comments in the code to explain what was going wrong.

```js
post = [
    {postTitle: 'Title1', key: 'key1'},
    {postTitle: 'Title2', key: 'key2'}
];

comment = [
    {key: 'key1', c: "comment1"},
    {key: 'key1', c: "comment2"},
    {key: 'key2', c: "commentA"},
    {key: 'key2', c: "commentB"},
    {key: 'key2', c: "commentC"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < post.length; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < comment.length; j++) {
    if (post[i].key === comment[j].key) {
      // Only set post[i].comment = [] when it is undefined (Only when the first comment is being added)
      if (typeof post[i].comment === 'undefined') {
        post[i].comment = [];
      }
      // Push only the comment, instead of [comment[j].c]
      post[i].comment.push(comment[j].c);
    } else {
      console.log('no comment to add');
    }
  }
}

console.log('post:', post);
console.log('comment:', comment);
```

**Another approach:**

Use [Array.find](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp) to get the post this comment is related to, then us `Array.isArray` to check if `post.comments` is already there, push it, else create `post.comments` key

```js
posts = [
    {postTitle: 'Title1', key: 'key1'},
    {postTitle: 'Title2', key: 'key2'}
];

comments = [
    {key: 'key1', c: "comment1"},
    {key: 'key1', c: "comment2"},
    {key: 'key2', c: "commentA"},
    {key: 'key2', c: "commentB"},
    {key: 'key2', c: "commentC"}
];

result = comments.map((comment) => {
  let post = posts.find(o => o.key === comment.key);
  Array.isArray(post.comments) ? post.comments.push(comment.c) : post.comments = [comment.c];
});

console.log('posts', posts);
console.log('comments', comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) functions to obtain the desired result

Please try the following example

```js
const post = [
    { postTitle: 'Title1', key: 'key1' },
    { postTitle: 'Title2', key: 'key2' }
];

const comment = [
    { key: 'key1', c: 'comment1' },
    { key: 'key1', c: 'comment2' },
    { key: 'key2', c: 'commentA' },
    { key: 'key2', c: 'commentB' },
    { key: 'key2', c: 'commentC' }
];

const newPost = [
    {
        postTitle: 'Title1',
        key: 'key1',
        comment: ['comment1', 'comment2']
    },
    {
        postTitle: 'Title2',
        key: 'key2',
        comment: ['commentA', 'commentB', 'commentC']
    }
];

const result = post.map(p => {
    const obj = Object.assign({}, p);

    obj.comment = comment.filter(c => c.key === p.key).map(c => c.c);

    return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you are only getting the last comment of each `postTitle` is because this if statement,

```
        if (post[i].key === comment[j].key) {
            // each time the post[i].key === comment[j].key
            // the line below is resetting the post[i].comment array to an
            // empty array
            post[i].comment = [];
            post[i].comment.push([comment[j].c]);
        }
```

you should write instead

```
for (var i = 0; i < post.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < comment.length; j++) {
        if (post[i].key === comment[j].key) {
         // line below will check if there isn't a post[i].comment array 
         // declared yet
         if (!post[i].comment){
            post[i].comment = [];
         }
           post[i].comment.push(comment[j].c);
        }
        else {
        console.log('no comment to add');        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps.